# SQL error during installing "Charity Checkout" extention

Tags: extensions, mysql, error, sql, reports

I received this error during installing the "[Charity checkout](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/charity-checkout.html)" extension on magento 1.8

```
a:5:{i:0;s:237:"Error in file: "/home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/local/GoodLabs/CharityCheckout/sql/charitycheckout_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'donation_amount'";i:1;s:1092:"#0 /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '0.1.3')
#2 /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('0.1.3')
#3 /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

This is some additional details:

```
PDOException Object
(
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'donation_amount'
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 42S21
    [file:protected] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
    [line:protected] => 228
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
                    [line] => 228
                    [function] => execute
                    [class] => PDOStatement
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 110
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php
                    [line] => 291
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php
                    [line] => 479
                    [function] => execute
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Statement
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
                    [line] => 238
                    [function] => query
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 428
                    [function] => query
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 347
                    [function] => query
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL
                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 617
                    [function] => raw_query
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL
                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 599
                    [function] => multi_query
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount_invoiced` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `base_donation_amount_invoiced` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount_refunded` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `base_donation_amount_refunded` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_quote_address` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_quote_address` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_invoice` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_invoice` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_creditmemo` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_creditmemo` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;

                        )

                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 933
                    [function] => multiQuery
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount_invoiced` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `base_donation_amount_invoiced` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount_refunded` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `base_donation_amount_refunded` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_quote_address` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_quote_address` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_invoice` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_invoice` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_creditmemo` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_creditmemo` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;

                        )

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/local/GoodLabs/CharityCheckout/sql/charitycheckout_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
                    [line] => 24
                    [function] => run
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount_invoiced` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `base_donation_amount_invoiced` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount_refunded` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `base_donation_amount_refunded` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_quote_address` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_quote_address` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_invoice` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_invoice` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_creditmemo` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_creditmemo` ADD  `base_donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;

                        )

                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 624
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/local/GoodLabs/CharityCheckout/sql/charitycheckout_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
                        )

                    [function] => include
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 421
                    [function] => _modifyResourceDb
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => install
                            [1] => 
                            [2] => 0.1.3
                        )

                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 327
                    [function] => _installResourceDb
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0.1.3
                        )

                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 235
                    [function] => applyUpdates
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                    [line] => 417
                    [function] => applyAllUpdates
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                    [line] => 343
                    [function] => _initModules
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [17] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/app/Mage.php
                    [line] => 683
                    [function] => run
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [scope_code] => 
                                    [scope_type] => store
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [18] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/golbon/domains/golbon.ir/public_html/index.php
                    [line] => 87
                    [function] => run
                    [class] => Mage
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => store
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [errorInfo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S21
            [1] => 1060
            [2] => Duplicate column name 'donation_amount'
        )

)
```

I removed all the extensions files but error report does not gone away.

What should i do to fix this issue?

Comment: Well, as error says `Duplicate column name 'donation_amount'`. Clean up your DB and try again.

Comment: There isn't any duplicate field in DB.
I added additional details to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim is right. Your query is:

```
ALTER TABLE  `golosales_flat_order` ADD  `donation_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL
```

and your error is:

> SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'donation_amount'

This is quite obvious. Remove the column or avoid to run this install script.

Comment: I want to avoid this install script. 

So i removed all the extension's files and recovered my last full backup.

But error report is still there.

Comment: but now the error is something else I would assume? Did you clean the cache?

Comment: Yes. I cleaned the cache. can you see golbon.ir without any issue? what about golbon.ir/admin?

Comment: so it is a kind of cache issue. thank you very much Fabian.